# Polarity vs Acidic Strength (Alcohols and Inorganic acids)

Tags: alcohols, polarity

If $\ce{HI}$ is more acidic than $\ce{HCl}$ because less polarity in $\ce{H-I}$ makes it easier to donate $\ce{H+}$ ion thus increasing its acidic strength, how does more polarity in $\ce{O-H}$ bond in primary alcohols (and also water) due to less electron releasing alkyl group translate to more acidic strength??

Comment: Less polarity alone does not mean more acidity. If it did, hydrocarbons would be very acidic.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the reason that H-I is a strong acid is that the valence orbitals of iodine are simply too large to overlap well with the small valence orbital of hydrogen.

Comment: I hold the view that the X-H bond needs to be polarized to some degree to make the hydrogen have some positive charge. Consider for a moment the hydrogen atoms bonded to ruthenium in RuH2(CO)(PCy3)3. These are very basic hydrides as they have partial negative charge chartacter and will act as Bronsted bases. While the hydrogen atom in HCo(CO)5 has a strong partial positive charge and acts as a Bronsted acid with great ease.